# Load fxml into existing scene AND have access to new fxml's variables

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to find a way to load a new fxml file into an anchor pane in an existing Scene. I am NOT trying to create a new scene and set the current stage to that Scene. I must keep using the same scene I already have as I am only putting the new fxml file into a part of it. I managed to load a fxml file into the anchor pane. However, Scene.lookup() will not return the variables from the newly loaded fxml file. I need a way to access the variables from the new fxml file:

```
                Scene = mainGui.getMainScenes().get(0);
                let guiAnchor = mainGui.getGuiAnchorPane();
                let pane = loader.load();
                javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(pane, 0);
                javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(pane, 0);
                javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(pane, 0);
                javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(pane, 0);

                //This line fails
                Scene.lookup("#sidelabel" + (i + 1)).setText(values[i]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to use `Scene.lookup()` for this. Just get a reference to the new FXML file's controller instead ...

Comment: Did you create a custom node type called `let`???

Comment: I didn't mention it because I didn't want to make the problem more complex but the reason I am using Scene.lookup is because this code is in Javascript via Nashorn. using @FXML is not possible with nashorn so I have to look items up this way. let is a javascript keyword.

Comment: anyone know how to do this and access the variables from the loaded fxml?